# Array from the contents of all elements of a specific class on a page

Tags: javascript, html

We are building a free database and I got some boring copy-paste work I want to speed up a bit.

I want to create an HTML page which, when fed a link, gets me an array of all the contents inside certain classes of the page linked. All pages I want to extract information from are made the same way, using the same class names.

They look something like this:

```
<ul class="section">
    <li class="article">
        <div class="author">
            <span class="FamilyName">Author1's Family Name </span>
            <span class="GivenName">Author1's Given Name</span>: 
        </div>
        <div class="titles">
            <a href="url_to_work.htm" title="Click here to read">
            <span class="title">Title of Work 1</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="section">
    <li class="article">
        <div class="author">
            <span class="FamilyName">Author2's Family Name </span>
            <span class="GivenName">Author2's Given Name</span>: 
        </div>
        <div class="titles">
            <a href="url_to_work.htm" title="Click here to read">
            <span class="title">Title of Work 2</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So basically I want to get an array of the authors' full names, and another one of the works' titles (the "title" spans). Like:

```
names = ["Author1's Family Name", "Author1's Given Name", "Author2's Family Name", "Author2's Given Name" ... etc.]
titles = ["Title of Work 1", "Title of Work 2", ... etc.]
```

From there, I can make the lists I want.

Is this possible with HTML & JS?

Comment: get contents either via iframe or xhtp then use DOMPaser. `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("span[class*=Name]")` for the fist case and `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("span.title")` for the second. Is this what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.querySelectorAll` & `innerHTML`.Using `document.querySelectorAll` get all the elements with class `.sections`. The iterate over it using `forEach`
You can create an array of object with key as `familyName` and `givenName` and an key `id`. This `id` will be used to get the the relevant title from `titleArray`

```js
var getAllSection = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
var nameArray = [];
var titleArray = [];
getAllSection.forEach(function(item, index) {
  let obj = {
    familyName: item.querySelector('.FamilyName').innerHTML.trim(),
    givenName: item.querySelector('.GivenName').innerHTML.trim(),
    id: index
  }
  let obj2 = {
    title: item.querySelector('.title').innerHTML.trim(),
    id: index
  }
  nameArray.push(obj);
  titleArray.push(obj2)
});
console.log(nameArray, titleArray)
```

```html
<ul class="section">
  <li class="article">
    <div class="author">
      <span class="FamilyName">Author1's Family Name </span>
      <span class="GivenName">Author1's Given Name</span>:
    </div>
    <div class="titles">
      <a href="url_to_work.htm" title="Click here to read">
        <span class="title">Title of Work 1</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="section">
  <li class="article">
    <div class="author">
      <span class="FamilyName">Author2's Family Name </span>
      <span class="GivenName">Author2's Given Name</span>:
    </div>
    <div class="titles">
      <a href="url_to_work.htm" title="Click here to read">
        <span class="title">Title of Work 2</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```